# PHP md5_file not the same on different machine

Tags: php, md5-file

I have two simple PHP scripts: testHash.php and me.php. The testHash.php is simply doing a `md5_file` function to the me.php and printing out the result

**testHash.php** contains:

```
<?php 
 $test = md5_file(__DIR__."/me.php"); 
 echo $test;
 echo phpinfo();
?>
```

and **me.php** contains:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

I have uploaded both script to two different Webserver using an FTP Tool (FileZilla) without of course touching the files. One is a local virtual machine and the other is a public Webserver.The output of the `$test` variable was different from the other. Both webserver operates on LAMP framework

1. Local VM Webserver = 7633bbfa20ed2d29a55338913048eff0
2. Public Webserver = 3a65329165abe28a485bed663da5e298

Why are they different from each other? Are there external factors (framework, PHP Versions, PHP configuration files) which affects the computation of the hash. Thank You.

Comment: it depends on the upload method you are using in filezilla. if it's binary, the md5 checksum should be the same, if you used ascii the checksum can be different.

Comment: yes that was the problem it was set to auto. thanks @RaphaelMüller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The md5's are different if the files are.

If you're transfering your file in ascii-mode, something in them could change, like the line endings changing from CRLF to LF.

Comment: Thanks so much. Il keep in mind the mode of transfer of my FTP tool. In my FileZilla->Transfer->Transfer Transfer Type was set to auto. I just set it to Binary. Thanks a lot